# Change text color of option menu when we use app:showAsAction="always"

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, optionmenu

I am using toolbar and use option for corresponding actions. My problem is this I want to show "SAVE" text on toolbar with white color, I apply many styles but it always appear as black. But when option appear as popup then text color is always white . I google this a lot , but have no solution.

Here is my code :

toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    android:background="@drawable/tb_header"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

**styles**

```
 <style name="MStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:panelBackground">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>

    </style>

<style name ="MyPopupMenu" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
    </style>


****Option menu**** 

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.doubtfire.userprofiles.ParentProfileActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_skip"
        android:title="@string/menu_str_skip"

        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>


****I even apply code at onPrepareOptionMenu**** 



   @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            for (int i=0; i<menu.size(); i++) {
                MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(i);
                String title = mi.getTitle().toString();
                Spannable newTitle = new SpannableString(title);
                newTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, newTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                mi.setTitle(newTitle);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

in `MStyle`, as is shown below:

```
<style name="MStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

  ...

  <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  <!-- for appcompat-->
  <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

This change colour of menu item when SAVE item will be visible on `ActionBar`

Comment: This is not Working :(

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood you. Do you want to change text of menu item on Action bar? That right? If yes this should works. Did you added your style to the `Activity ` in Manifest?

Comment: Yes , I want extactly what you say , and I added this theme to while app in application tag  as

Comment: <application
        android:name=".utils.AppData"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MStyle" >

Comment: Try add it for activity tag : <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MStyle"

Comment: It is very strange for me because it works fine in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75783/discussion-between-poor-and-konrad-krakowiak).

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak this working in 5.0 but not in 4.0.. ?how can do the same for all version

Comment: any concrete example . there is a lot of confusion in different versions api .

Answer (score 2):

To change the color of the text in `Toolbar` menu use below code.

```
<style name="MStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
         ....   

           <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>

</style>
```