# ActionBar Optionmenu Customization (ANDROID)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to change text color of menu item ***programmatically*** in option menu of ActionBar with its showAsAction parameter set to  `app:showAsAction="always"`.

I can change the text color of menu item when its `app:showAsAction="never"` using this -

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem liveitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(liveitem.getTitle().toString());
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
    liveitem.setTitle(s);

    return true;
}
```

Any suggestion on how to change it if its `"always"` .

I got a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766411/change-text-color-of-option-menu-when-we-use-appshowasaction-always) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352963/change-toolbar-menu-item-color-non-hidden-action). but this answer is not concrete and cant be applied to all api versions.

Comment: <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#yourcolor</item> this should help you change it.

Comment: but i want to do it runtime .

Comment: You can change the style at runtime. R.style.menucolor. use this to change at runtime,

Comment: can you make an answer on this ? with some code example.